# Angular 2 - Data not displayed in HTML from Service

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, service

I'm new to Angular and have made a CRUD app using Spring Boot and REST web services. Now I have one component which is displaying the data from database in tabular form. I have created a service to handle the JSON data from Spring Boot web service and I'm able to **`console.log`** the contents from the component but they are not reflected in the HTML. Don't know where I'm doing wrong. Would appreciate any help, been banging my head for the past day. The stacktrace from console and code snippet are below

**browser console**

```
    GET 
http://localhost:4200/ [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 21ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/css/Roboto.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/css/MaterialIcons.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 0ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/css/material.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/js/popper.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 0ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 0ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/js/material.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 0ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 0ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/styles.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 18ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1ms]
ERROR TypeError: _co.user is undefined
Stack trace:
View_AppComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:315:9
debugUpdateDirectives@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14886:12
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14033:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14384:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14316:13
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14039:5
callWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15287:39
debugCheckAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14824:12
ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11801:9
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:58
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:13
ApplicationRef.prototype._loadComponent@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6175:9
ApplicationRef.prototype.bootstrap@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6063:9
PlatformRef.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5783:74
PlatformRef.prototype._moduleDoBootstrap@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5783:13
PlatformRef.prototype.bootstrapModuleFactory/</</<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5704:21
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:17
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvoke@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4952:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:17
Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:873:52
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:17
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4943:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:25
AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8

ERROR CONTEXT Object { view: Object, nodeIndex: 129, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object }AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8

Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.core.js:3859:9
ERROR TypeError: _co.user is undefined
Stack trace:
View_AppComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:315:9
debugUpdateDirectives@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14886:12
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14033:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14384:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14316:13
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14039:5
callWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15287:39
debugCheckAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14824:12
ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11801:9
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:58
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:13
ApplicationRef/<.next/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5942:99
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:17
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvoke@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4952:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:17
Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:24
NgZone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4769:54
ApplicationRef/<.next@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5942:69
EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4538:36
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:244:13
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:191:17
Subscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:132:9
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:96:13
Subject.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js:65:17
EventEmitter.prototype.emit@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4518:24
checkStable@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4917:13
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onHasTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4965:21
ZoneDelegate.prototype.hasTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:445:21
ZoneDelegate.prototype._updateTaskCount@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:465:17
Zone.prototype._updateTaskCount@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:289:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:209:25
drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:25
AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8

ERROR CONTEXT Object { view: Object, nodeIndex: 129, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object }AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8

GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/imgs/avatar.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
OPTIONS 
XHR 
http://localhost:8080/api/users [HTTP/1.1 200  1113ms]
GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1483ms]
GET 
XHR 
http://localhost:8080/api/users [HTTP/1.1 200  4068ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/896/bjb5gb5f/websocket [HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 62ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/assets/css/material.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
ERROR TypeError: _co.user is undefined
Stack trace:
View_AppComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:315:9
debugUpdateDirectives@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14886:12
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14033:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14384:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14316:13
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14039:5
callWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15287:39
debugCheckAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14824:12
ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11801:9
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:58
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:13
ApplicationRef/<.next/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5942:99
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:17
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvoke@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4952:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:17
Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:24
NgZone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4769:54
ApplicationRef/<.next@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5942:69
EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4538:36
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:244:13
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:191:17
Subscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:132:9
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:96:13
Subject.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js:65:17
EventEmitter.prototype.emit@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4518:24
checkStable@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4917:13
onLeave@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4996:5
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4946:17
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:499:24
ZoneTask/this.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:488:28
scheduleTask/target[XHR_LISTENER]@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:2924:25
AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8

ERROR CONTEXT Object { view: Object, nodeIndex: 129, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object }AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8

*** --- [{"username":"admin","password":"admin"},{"username":"test","password":"test"},{"username":"user","password":"user"}] --- ***app.component.ts:24:13
ERROR TypeError: _co.user is undefined
Stack trace:
View_AppComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:315:9
debugUpdateDirectives@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14886:12
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14033:5
callViewAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14384:21
execComponentViewsAction@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14316:13
checkAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14039:5
callWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:15287:39
debugCheckAndUpdateView@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14824:12
ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11801:9
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:58
ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:6109:13
ApplicationRef/<.next/<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5942:99
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:17
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvoke@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4952:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:17
Zone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:24
NgZone.prototype.run@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4769:54
ApplicationRef/<.next@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:5942:69
EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4538:36
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:244:13
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:191:17
Subscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:132:9
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:96:13
Subject.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subject.js:65:17
EventEmitter.prototype.emit@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4518:24
checkStable@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4917:13
onLeave@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4996:5
forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/zone._inner<.onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4946:17
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:499:24
patchEventTarget/invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:9
patchEventTarget/globalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17
AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8

ERROR CONTEXT Object { view: Object, nodeIndex: 129, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object }AppComponent.ngfactory.js:220:8
```

**user.ts**

```
export class User {
username: string;
password: string;
constructor(){}
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserService } from './user.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private baseUrl: string='http://localhost:8080/api';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  private options = new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers});
  private user: User;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + '/users', this.options)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

  errorHandler(){
    return Observable.throw(Error || "!!! SERVER ERROR !!!");
  }    
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public users: User[];

  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.getUsers().subscribe((users)=>{
      this.users=users;
    }, (error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }    
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center mt-2" *ngIf="users">
    <thead class="blue darken-4">
      <tr>
        <th class="white-text">
          <strong>Username</strong>
        </th>
        <th class="white-text">
          <strong>Password</strong>
        </th>
        <th class="white-text">
          <strong>Actions</strong>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users">            
        <td class="pt-4">{{user.username}}</td>
        <td class="pt-4">{{user.password}}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm w-25 waves-attach modal-trigger blue accent-3 text-white" (click)="updateUser(user)">
            <span class="material-icons">build</span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm w-25 waves-attach blue accent-3 text-white" (click)="deleteUser(user)">
            <span class="material-icons">delete_forever</span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: post the complete code of your template

Comment: Edited and added the HTML **ngFor** part

Comment: what do you see when you do console.log(this.users);

Comment: may be  styling issue, can you post the full template html code

Comment: @Sajeetharan it displays
    [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: ok post what you see when you do console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users));

Comment: @Sajeetharan it displays the contents

**[{"username":"admin","password":"admin"},{"username":"test","password":"test"},{"username":"user","password":"user"}]**

Comment: try just initializing the array as public users: User[] =[];

Comment: @Sajeetharan that didn't solve the issue sadly.

Comment: @TweaknFreak Can you post your full html  template?

Comment: what is the actuall error

Comment: @TruckDriver added the full HTML snippet in the post

Posted entire browser console stuff

Comment: Please create a demo.